# Move one column to another

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-update

I have table

```
Employee 
{
EmpId,
FirstName,
LastName,
DeptId
}

Department
{
DeptId,
DeptName,
Specialization
}
```

Now I had added specialization column to `Employee`, so now the new `Employee` table is:

```
Employee 
{
EmpId,
FirstName,
LastName,
DeptId,
Specialization
}
```

Now I want update script to move specialization data from Department to `Employee`.

Comment: The question is not that clear. Do you ask for a query, an update-sql or  a sql-script which changes the table columns?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UPDATE from SELECT using SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/update-from-select-using-sql-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the update-join syntax:

```
UPDATE e
SET    e.Specialization = d.Specialization
FROM   Employee e
JOIN   Department d ON e.DeptId = d.DeptId
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple nested queries;

```
Update Employee Ee
Set    Specialization = (SELECT Specialization
                         FROM   Department Dpt
                         Where  Dpt.DeptId = Ee.DeptId)
```